# ruby on rails Postgres duplicate key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several code tables that were working fine.  Now when I try to add a record, I'm getting:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint  "classcodes_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
```

Model code:

```
class Classcode < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :worequests
default_scope :order => 'classcode ASC'
def class_desc
"#{self.classcode} - #{self.classdesc}"
end

scope :archived, where(:archive => true)
scope :active, where(:archive => false)

end
```

Schema:

```
 create_table "classcodes", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "classcode"
  t.string   "classdesc"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "archive",    :default => false
end
```

Classcodes has the key = id [PK] serial and contains records 1 through 9 already.

Any ideas?

Thanks

PS - I was advised to run a rake db:reset - and now the problem is gone - but, now I need to reload my data.

Comment: I kept trying to enter the new record and now it's at key = 16 and I'm getting the same error even though there are only 9 records in the table.

Comment: Is it possible that the table containing the serial value in your database is not up to date?  PostgreSQL stores this as a "sequence" in its metadata.  UPDATE: answered, sequence is working.

Comment: How would I find out?  I ran pgAdmin/maintenance/vacuum and analyze on the table.  BTW - it's more than one table giving me the error.  Plus, the same app running on Heroku works fine.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post your model code or the relevant section of your schema.rb.  Also, what key values (ids) are used in the 9 rows -- from a psql> prompt, run "select id from classcodes;"

Comment: I also rebooted my iMac to see if restarting Postgres would help - same errors.

Comment: The records in the table are using keys: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: OK, after seeing the model, I am not sure why PG is complaining about "classcodes_pkey" -- the model should be backed by a table called "statuscodes" and have a primary key "statuscodes_pkey" -- if there's some mixup, then maybe PG is using a sequence from a different table for some reason.  Can you also post your schema.rb ... and is there some other table `classcodes`?

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong table - I just updated it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20257/discussion-between-tharrison-and-dave-burton)